# How to get Screen mouse coordinates into POINTS structure

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

I'm having to do some manual windows message sending for a custom drawn WPF window. Specifically, when the user left mouse downs in the title bar, I am having to manually send the [WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms645620%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.

So far, I have:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
```

The fun part is getting the value to put into the lParam. It needs to be an Int32 (DWORD) representing the X and Y coordinates of the mouse.

There is a [macro defined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd145043%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for creating the necessary structure, but it isn't helping me. So, the question is this:

In a WPF Window, how do I correctly fire this message with the correct value passed in as the lParam argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lParam = x | (y << 16);
```

Where x and y are the coordinates.

To extract the values from a message:

```
int x = lParam & 0xFFFF;
int y = (lParam >> 16) & 0xFFFF;
```

Comment: This fails with negative mouse coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer will fail with negative mouse coordinates, which you may see when you have multiple monitors.  I think this will work:

```
int lParam = (ushort)x | (y << 16);

x = (short)lParam;
y = (short)(lParam >> 16);
```

Comment: In case there are others trying to figure out why this does not work in Java, Java does bitwise operations with ints. so even if you cast it to short it won't work for negative x values